# Read Elements from Stack without losing them in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack

Quick question. Let's say I've got a Stack, where I pop things.

```
var stack = [];
stack.push(2);       // stack is now [2]
stack.push(5);       // stack is now [5]
```

How do I read the last element, since, let's say I don't have the number of pops? For example a click function adds a variable to the stack and I need to use the last added variable, which command do I use?

And also, if I want to check all the Objects of the stack with another variable is it simply a for-loop with

```
stack[i] != x
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the last element to a variable:

```
var x = stack[stack.length - 1]
```

If your array elements are *objects* you'll want to check a *property* of an object against a variable.

For example you might want to see if there's one or more objects with a key/value pair of 'number'/2 in the array. You might use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check:

```
var x = 2;
var arr = [{ number: 1 }, { number: 2 }, { number: 3 }];

var some = arr.some(function (el) {
  return el.number === x;
}); // true
```

Be sure to [check out the various array methods on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 1):

Read last element in array

```
stack[stack.length-1]
```

`stack[i] !== x` is better comparison

`!=` won't catch that difference for instance `null != undefined`

These are connected with truthy and falsy values in javascript.